# Error will not go away, but not even anything on the line

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Why will this error not go away? Anybody know? It says build successful, but this line remains, even after closing.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to declare an ivar outside of the ivar block. This would be the `SwitchingViews *switchingViews;` line. That is almost certainly the source of the error.

Your class definition should look like:

```
@interface YourAwesomeClass : NSObject 
{
    SwitchingViews *switchingViews;
}
```